# Removing an Image from Canvas Grid on Double Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, kineticjs

I'm Dragging and Drooping an image from a toolbar onto a canvas and then moving it around in the canvas.Currently I'm able to load multiple images onto a canvas multiple times from the toolbar and delete them on double click as shown in the link below.

http://jsfiddle.net/gkefk/33/

I want to add the same functionality on a grid of deleting a particular copy of the image from the canvas grid when the user double clicks on that particular image.For this I'm triggering the same jQuery event on double click which i used in the 1st link.

```
$("#image").dblclick(function(){
layer.remove();
});
```

Even though I'm double clicking on a particular copy the image,that particular copy is not getting deleted from the grid.I can't understand what I'm doing wrong..Please Help

The link to the fiddle containing the jQuery event

http://jsfiddle.net/Lucy1/wQ8YA/31/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the clone instead of the image

```
$clone.on('dblclick', function () {
    $clone.remove();
    layer.draw();
});
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RobinvdA/wQ8YA/34/)